# Irregular line spacing between references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, line-spacing

I can hardly solve an editing problem concerning bibliography: the line spacing between references is irregular in the middle of one page as follows. I wonder if I can find any suggestion here.

[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[10.5pt, leqno,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[authordate,autocite=inline,backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{url}  
\urlstyle{same}
\bibliography{sa}
\begin{document}
\cite{burdett2012mapping,Cammers2020footsteps,Dahl2009,De2016,DeCerteau1988,Door2012,Fonseca2019,Grauwin2014,Gutierrez2013,Jacobs1961,Jameson2019}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\urlstyle{sf}
\end{document}
```

The bib file is:

```
@article{burdett2012mapping,
  title={Mapping Scales of Urban Identity},
  author={Burdett, Ricky},
  journal={Architectural Design},
  volume={82},
  number={6},
  pages={92--97},
  year={2012},
  doi={10.1002/ad.1501}
}

@article{Cammers2020footsteps,
  title={From Footsteps to Data to Art: Seeing (through) a Bridge},
  author={Cammers-Goodwin, Sage and Nagenborg, Michael},
  journal={Contemporary Aesthetics},
  volume={8},
  number={Special Issue},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Contemporary Aesthetics},
  url={https://contempaesthetics.org/2020/07/16/from-footsteps-to-data-to-art-seeing-through-a-bridge/}
}

@article{Dahl2009,
  title={`It all happened so slowly' -- On controlling function creep in forensic DNA databases},
  author={Dahl, Johanne Yttri and S{\ae}tnan, Ann Rudinow},
  journal={International Journal of Law, Crime and Justice},
  volume={37},
  number={3},
  pages={83--103},
  year={2009}
}

@article{Kung2014,
  title={Exploring universal patterns in human home-work commuting from mobile phone data},
  author={Kung, Kevin S. and Greco, Kael and Sobolevsky, Stanislav and Ratti, Carlo},
  journal={PloS One},
  volume={9},
  number={6},
  pages={e96180},
  year={2014},
  doi={10.1371/journal.pone.0096180}
}

@inproceeding{De2016,
  title={The Death and Life of Great Italian Cities: A Mobile Phone Data Perspective},
  author={De Nadai, Marco and Staiano, Jacopo and Larcher, Roberto and Sebe, Nicu and Quercia, Daniele and Lepri, Bruno},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 25th international conference on world wide web},
  pages={413--423},
  year={2016},
  doi={10.1145/2872427.2883084}
}

@inbook{DeCerteau1988,
author={De Certeau, Michel},
year={1988},
title={Walking the City},
booktitle={The Practice of Everyday Life},
translator={Rendall,Steven},
pages={91--110},
address={London},
publisher={University of California Press}
}

@online{Door2012,
author={Door, Steeph},
year={2012},
title={Meer dan 5000 databases met persoonsgegeven bij overheid},
journal={Sargasso},
volume={10},
url={http://sargasso.nl/meer-dan-5000-databases-met-persoonsgegevens-bij-overheid/}
}

@online{Fonseca2019,
author={Fonseca, Ryan},
year={2019}, 
title={Scooters, Scooters Everywhere. Here's How LA's Grand Experiment Is Going},
journal={LAist},
year={2019},
url={https://laist.com/news/las-big-scooter-experiment}
}

@incollection{Grauwin2014,
  title={Towards a Comparative Science of Cities: Using Mobile Traffic Records in New York, London, and Hong Kong},
  author={Grauwin, S{\'e}bastian and Sobolevsky, Stanislav and Moritz, Simon and G{\'o}dor, Istv{\'a}n and Ratti, Carlo},
  booktitle={Computational approaches for urban environments},
  pages={363--387},
  year={2014},
  editor={Helbich, Marco and Arsanjani, Jamal Jokar and Leitner, Michael},
  doi={10.1007/978-3-319-11469-9_15}
}

@inproceeding{Gutierrez2013,
  title={SmartSantander: Internet of Things Research and Innovation through Citizen Participation},
  author={Guti{\'e}rrez, Ver{\'o}nica and Galache, Jose A and S{\'a}nchez, Luis and Mu{\~n}oz, Luis and Hern{\'a}ndez-Mu{\~n}oz, Jos{\'e} M. and Fernandes, Joao and Presser, Mirko},
  booktitle={The Future Internet},
  series={Future Internet Assembly},
  pages={173--186},
  year={2013},
  address={Berlin},
  publisher={Springer},
  editor={Galis, Alex and Gavras, Anastasius},
  doi={10.1007/978-3-642-38082-2_15}
}

@book{Jacobs1961,
author={Jacobs, Jane},
year={1961},
title={The Death and Life of Great American Cities},
address={New York},
publisher={Random House Inc}
}

@article{Jameson2019,
author = {Jameson, Shazade and Richter, Christine and Taylor, Linnet},
title = {People's strategies for perceived surveillance in Amsterdam Smart City},
journal = {Urban Geography},
volume = {40},
number = {10},
pages = {1467--1484},
year  = {2019},
doi = {10.1080/02723638.2019.1614369}
}
```

Comment: please supply an example document that produces the  outout shown.

Comment: unrelated but `article` does not have a `10.5pt` option.

Comment: We will also need to see enough of your `.bib` file to reproduce this behaviour. I cannot remember having come across such a weird spacing and at least at the moment I think this should not happen. I failed to reproduce the spacing from the screenshot with other generic entries that were available to me.

Comment: Thanks you Carlisle. I substitute 10.5pt with 12pt/11pt, unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to upload bib, moewe. I compile these two files through pdflatex and get irregular line spacing. Even if I delete \usepackage{url} and \urlstyle{..}, the problem still remains. I cannot understand which part goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example produces not only weirdly spaced output, but also the following error

```
! Package biblatex Error: No driver for 'inproceeding' found.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.136 \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

**Never ignore error messages.** You cannot expect usable output after an error! If your editor hides error messages from you, use another editor.

The solution here is simple: There is a small typo in your `.bib` file

- `@inproceeding` should be `@inproceedings` with an **`s`** at the end. (In the example this is relevant for `De2016` and `Gutierrez2013`.)

The entries with the incorrect `@inproceeding` were being ignored and caused an empty line to appear creating the impression of a larger space between the surrounding entries.

---

`biblatex-chicago` behaves slightly different in this respect from most other `biblatex` styles. Most `biblatex` have (or inherit) something like

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{*}{misc}
```

which means that `biblatex` uses the `@misc` driver for entry types for which it does not have a driver setup. `biblatex-chicago` has no such provision and will therefore error if an unknown entry type is used.

Comment: After substituting all @inproceeding{..} with @inproceedings{...}, it perfectly works. Thank you moewe!

Comment: 1) You cannot expect usable output after an error!  (Indeed.) 2) After substituting all @inproceeding{..} with @inproceedings{...}, it perfectly works. 3) I also follow the second suggestion to insert  \DeclareBibliographyAlias{*}{misc} into the preambles. It also works with @inproceeding{...}. In the end, I take the first suggestion. Thank you moewe!

Comment: @W.Zhu Glad it works for you! Just to be absolutely clear I did not want to recommend `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` to resolve the problem. That was just an afterthought to explain *why* `biblatex-chicago` behaves differently (and why you probably cannot reproduce this with most other styles). In this case the best (and I think only proper) solution is to change to `@inproceedings`.

Comment: I agree with you that the proper solution is to write codes properly. I didn't expect that I would receive a serious reply. Thank you very much also for testing these codes with some bib file.